# How to properly clear the sql-database at the end of the program(room)?

Tags: android, database, android-room, viewmodel

*I guess common question which was answered a lot of times. But i can't find an answer.*
**How and where i could clear sql-database (room)?**

In my case, I have a database that I want to clear after entry/read at the end of the program.

I have ViewModel, and I assumed I could clear database, just use method to database with Query-annotation: `"DELETE * FROM database"` in ViewModel method `onCleared()`.

This way works, but only when I close the program by clicking on the *"Exit"* button created by myself, which has a method `finish()`. If i try to close program use the android navigation bar (by swipe up from list of apps working in background), database isn't cleared.

I also use an activity and have an activity method `onDestroy()` maybe i should use it.

*Please tell me how this is usually done.*